# Resizing SVG Circle Radius Using CSS Animation

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to animate an SVG circle's radius attribute with CSS. Whilst (using the Firefox Inspect Element tool) I can see that the animation itself is setup and running correctly, the size of the ".innerCircle" doesn't visibly change.

If you can spot anything that I've obviously missed, or help in any way I'd be greatly appreciative. I'm rather new to this, so if I have gone about this wrong, please be kind!

I've pasted my files underneath for reference.

Thanks again.

```css
@keyframes buttonTransition {
  from {
    r: 5%;
  }
  to {
    r: 25%;
  }
}

.innerCircle {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: buttonTransition;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href = "styling.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css"></link>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg class = "button" expanded = "true" height = "100px" width = "100px">
      <circle cx = "50%" cy = "50%" r = "35%" stroke = "#000000" stroke-width = "10%" fill = "none"/>
      <circle class = "innerCircle" cx = "50%" cy = "50%" r = "25%" fill = "#000000"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In SVG 1.1 the radius of a circle was an [attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html) and not a [CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html). SVG 2 changes this and instead makes the circle's radius a CSS property that's mapped to an attribute.

CSS animations animate CSS properties and do not animate attributes.

Firefox has now implemented this part of the SVG 2 specification so the testcase in the question will work now although it didn't when the question was written.

SMIL animations will work on attributes (and CSS properties).

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href = "styling.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg class = "button" expanded = "true" height = "100px" width = "100px">
            <circle cx = "50%" cy = "50%" r = "35%" stroke = "#000000" stroke-width = "10%" fill = "none"/>
            <circle class = "innerCircle" cx = "50%" cy = "50%" r = "25%" fill = "#000000">
              <animate attributeName="r" begin="0s" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" from="5%" to="25%"/>
            </circle>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead." -my console

Comment: @krummens presumably a future Chrome update will remove that deprecation warning as they've changed their mind.

Comment: Seriously? I've done quite a bit of svg with the idea of not being able to use <animate> and it's been rough. So I did all that for nothing?

Comment: 'fraid so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995387/what-is-pure-svg-and-what-is-smil/40995854#40995854

Comment: well it's 2020 now and SMIL still has [97%](https://caniuse.com/svg-smil) browser support...

Answer (score 10):

There is a simple alternative: animate element scale instead of circle radius. As of 2018, it is supported in Edge and all modern browsers.

SMIL animations is deprecated and only supported by browsers for legacy reasons. It may be dropped in the future and will never appear in Edge or some future browsers.

```css
@keyframes buttonTransition {
    from {
        transform: scale(0.2);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.innerCircle {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: buttonTransition;
    transform-origin: center center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href = "styling.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg class = "button" expanded = "true" height = "100px" width = "100px">
            <circle cx = "50%" cy = "50%" r = "35%" stroke = "#000000" stroke-width = "10%" fill = "none"/>
            <circle class = "innerCircle" cx = "50%" cy = "50%" r = "25%" fill = "#000000"/>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: SMIL animation may be deprecated but at least there's a polyfill for IE for it. There's no polyfill for CSS animation in IE that I know of.

Comment: @RobertLongson It's 2017. Who cares about IE? Edge will soon overtake it in popularity. Besides, CSS animation is IE10+ and nobody supports IE below 11 these days.

Comment: @RobertLongson This is a real bummer. Circle can be faked with border-radius in this particular case. In general, SVG can be replaced with backup png image for IE only and then animated using transforms

Comment: @RobertLongson Just looked into your profile. What's the deal with Firefox transform-origin not applied to SVG elements? It's very, very annoying. Chrome gets it right

Comment: @RobertLongson In other words, it's political. If enough UAa implement it right rather than according to whatever mistaken spec w3c publishes, they will be forced to fix it.

Comment: @RobertLongson [transform-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box) is the solution and it's still in the draft?

Comment: well, it's 2020 now and SMIL still has [97%](https://caniuse.com/svg-smil) browser support...

Answer (score 4):

OP query now works out of the box since some browser versions and **SVG2** support.

> Starting with SVG2, `cx`, `cy`, and `r` are Geometry Properties, meaning
> those attributes can also be used as CSS properties for that element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle

https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#TermPresentationAttribute

---

This is the same demo defining all the geometry from css. The same cascading rules apply, if a html attributes is declared, it will override stylings from the `style` attributes, and if a rule is declared  in the `style` attribute, it then override the `class` rules.

```css
@keyframes buttonTransition {
  from {
    r: 5%;
  }
  to {
    r: 25%;
  }
}

.button {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto
}

.outterCircle {
  cx: 50%;
  cy: 50%;
  r: 35%;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 10%;
  fill: none
}

.innerCircle {
  cx: 50%;
  cy: 50%;
  r: 25%;
  fill: #000000;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: buttonTransition
}
```

```html
<svg class="button">
  <circle class="outterCircle"/>
  <circle class="innerCircle"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still looking into how to do this I found a pretty good solution for a filled circle without using SMIL. This solution is a bit of a hack, and it will only work for circles that have a solid fill in them. Essentially what I did was animate the stroke width of these circles to appear as if they are growing.

My original circle

```
<circle cx="46" cy="46" r="2.8"/>
```

For this to work I set the radius of the circle to be close to be close to 0.

```
<circle cx="46" cy="46" r="0.01"/>
```

Then set a stroke width to be twice the amount of the original radius, and finally setup the animation of the stroke width.

```
@keyframes circle_animation {
    from {
        stroke-width: 0;
    }
}

circle {
    stroke-width: 5.6;
    animation: circle_animation .5s linear infinite;
}
```