# What is pure SVG and what is SMIL?

Tags: animation, svg, smil

*Context:* I'm working on an infographic in SVG. I want to have the document come to life thanks to animations, especially by **chaining animations**. I'm already familiar with SVG but started learning SVG animation only recently.

**Since SMIL is deprecated, I'm trying to produce animations in pure SVG.**

[Looking at this article (esp. the *Handy Dandy Replacement Reference Chart* at the end)](https://css-tricks.com/smil-is-dead-long-live-smil-a-guide-to-alternatives-to-smil-features/), I'm under the impression that I need to stop using suc hattributes:

```
fill="freeze"
repeatCount="indefinite" 
begin="hover" 
begin="circ-anim.begin + 1s"
```

…because they are part of SVG SMIL.

But, if I look at the [SVG reference on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element), I see `<animate>` and `<animateTransform>` inside the list, with no warning about them being SMIL, or the need to stop using them.

Moreover, it seems [Chrome normally warns against the use of SMIL animations in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965580/deprecated-smil-svg-animation-replaced-with-css-or-web-animations-effects-hover) but I can see no such warning when using `<animate>` or `<animateTransform>` (be it in an SVG document, or inside an HTML document that includes an inline or object SVG.)

Long story short, it's not clear to me **what is SMIL and what is pure SVG**. Can anyone shade some light on the topic? **Can I use `<animate>` and `<animateTransform>`?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SMIL is [no longer deprecated by Chrome](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM/YGEJBsjUAwAJ).

> We value all of your feedback, and it's clear that there are use cases serviced by SMIL that just don’t have high-fidelity replacements yet. As a result, we’ve decided to suspend our intent to deprecate and take smaller steps toward other options.

Basically SMIL in SVG is everything in the [Animation chapter of the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html).

That's the `<animate>` element, the `<set>` element, the `<animateMotion>` element and the `<animateTransform>` element. (the SVG specification also contains an `<animateColor>` element which should not be used, you can just replace that with animate).