# SVG animation not working in Firefox, Safari and IE

Tags: css, svg

I have a SMIL SVG that works in all browsers(apart from IE, obviously). I wanted to pull out the animations from my SVG into CSS. Worked out well enough except now  the SVG animation doesn't work in any browser, apartf from Chrome(obviously).

Here's the svg:

```
<svg width="135" height="140" viewBox="0 0 135 140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ddd">
    <rect class="sp-bars sp-e"  x="0" y="10" width="15" height="120" rx="6"></rect>
    <rect class="sp-bars sp-s"  x="30"  y="10" width="15" height="120" rx="6"></rect>
    <rect class="sp-bars sp-m"  x="60"  y="10" width="15" height="120" rx="6"></rect>
    <rect class="sp-bars sp-s"  x="90"  y="10" width="15" height="120" rx="6"></rect>
    <rect class="sp-bars sp-e"  x="120" y="10" width="15" height="120" rx="6"></rect>
</svg>
```

An here's the css:

```
.sp-e{
    animation: squeeze 1.2s 0.55s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: squeeze 1.2s 0.55s infinite;
    -moz-animation: squeeze 1.2s 0.55s infinite;
    -o-animation: squeeze 1.2s 0.55s infinite;
}

.sp-s{
    animation: squeeze 1.2s 0.30s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: squeeze 1.2s 0.30s infinite;
    -moz-animation: squeeze 1.2s 0.30s infinite;
    -o-animation: squeeze 1.2s 0.30s infinite;
}

.sp-m{
    animation: squeeze 1.2s 0s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: squeeze 1.2s 0s infinite;
    -moz-animation: squeeze 1.2s 0s infinite;
    -o-animation: squeeze 1.2s 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes squeeze {
    0%      { height: 120px; y: 10; }
    80%     { height: 40px; y: 50; }
    95%     { height: 140px; y: 0; }
    100%    { height: 120px; y: 10; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes squeeze {
    0%      { height: 120px; y: 10; }
    80%     { height: 40px; y: 50; }
    95%     { height: 140px; y: 0; }
    100%    { height: 120px; y: 10; }
}
@-moz-keyframes squeeze {
    0%      { height: 120px; y: 10; }
    80%     { height: 40px; y: 50; }
    95%     { height: 140px; y: 0; }
    100%    { height: 120px; y: 10; }
}
@-o-keyframes squeeze {
    0%      { height: 120px; y: 10; }
    80%     { height: 40px; y: 50; }
    95%     { height: 140px; y: 0; }
    100%    { height: 120px; y: 10; }
}
```

Comment: height is not yet a CSS property in Firefox and Safari and is therefore not animatable with CSS animations.

Comment: Is there any workaround?

Comment: Yes, SMIL. But you already know that.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I'm currently using. Wanted to switch to css because Chrome might depreciate SMIL in the future.

Comment: [They won't do that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995387/what-is-pure-svg-and-what-is-smil/40995854#40995854)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the link mate!