# Firefox :animate SVG radius only works with percentages

Tags: svg, firefox, css-animations, browser-support

I am trying to animate the SVG2 Geometry Property `r`, the [radius property](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/geometry.html#R) of a Circle Element.

I read that the property can be used as CSS property in browsers supporting SVG2 (see [Resizing SVG Circle Radius Using CSS Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409101/resizing-svg-circle-radius-using-css-animation/64267895#64267895)).

Now I notice that animating `r` does only seem to work in Firefox if I express values as [percentages](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#typedef-length-percentage). If I use absolute values, the circle is not being animated, see [minimum reproduction CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-butterfly-zmuew).

Does Firefox lack SVG2 support here?

Comment: Units are mandatory in CSS. If Chrome does not require units, that's a Chrome bug. If I put px in throughout then Firefox works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, stating lengths in pixel does the job.
The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#absolute-length) indeed says that absolute lenths must be given in physical units.
Omiting them will Chrome use `px` as fallback unit, while Firefox won't.